# Django - Make private page by user

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm currently developping a micro_blog to learn Django, and i didn't find the way to make a page only visible by one User.

ex: i want that each user got a private page on /profile/username/private .

How sould i do to make that only the user "username" got access to it?

For the moment, **every-user** can access to this page by typing the url.

I already put the `" @login_required "` on head of my func, but logged user can still access to the page.

Hope that you'll understand my issue,

Kind Regards,

[UPDATE]

I successfully made it by comparing the name of the current connected user with the name of the owner private page. As each username is unique in the DataBase, the way i did it works.

Comment: Check the usernames in your view and act accordingly: error/redirect or show page.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Create your own decorator that will validate the logged in user before going into the view and show the content accordingly. Put a check in the template that the logged in user is requesting the page. You can use both @login_required and your own decorator on your view.

Comment: How by modifying user group can i made it ? If i put the user in the same group it will be the same problem, no ? Otherwise, i must create one group per user ? it doesn't seem logic .. :/ I'm new in django, so maybe i make a mistake ^^'

Comment: I think i didn't understand your question before your edit. I do now.